# How do I insert text above a tableview

Tags: ios, textview, uitableview, tableview, xcode5

I am completely new to coding apps for ios devices. I just want to know how to insert text above a table. I already have a table in a tableViewController. I want to insert text above the table. So it will have text above the table and then a few cells underneath.

What should I do? Can someone tell me please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your view controller class:

```
-(void)addTextAbove:(NSString *)textAbove
{
    for (UIView* subView in self.view.subviews)
    {
        if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UITableView class]])
        {
            UILabel *tv = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 50)];

            [tv setText:textAbove];
            [tv setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
            [self.view addSubview:tv];

            CGRect frame = subView.frame;
            frame.origin.y = tv.frame.size.height;
            frame.size.height = frame.size.height - tv.frame.size.height;
            [subView setFrame:frame];
        }
    }
}
```

Call it any where you want:

```
[self addTextAbove:@"Txet Abouve"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `tableFooterView` property of your UITableView so you can put any `UIView` above the tableView. This `UIView` will scroll with the rest of the content.

If you are using Interface Builder you can drop a generic `UIView` in bottom margin of the `UITableView` and Interface Builder will automatically set it as the `tableFooterView`.

If you are creating the UI with code you can start just putting a `UILabel` with the desired text. You can hardcode the desired height:

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 40)];
label.text = @"Some text";
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
self.tableView.tableFooterView = label;
```

Or you can tell `UIKit` to calculate the height:

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
label.text = @"Some text";
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
[label sizeToFit];
self.tableView.tableFooterView = label;
```

Put any of the below code in your `viewDidLoad` method.